# Does a bound on the operator norm of a square matrix generalize to a rectangular matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, upper-lower-bounds, random-matrices, matrix-norms

**Setup:** Given that I have a random square matrix $X$ where each entry is generated independently and identically. Denote $\|X\|_{\text{op}}$ to be the operator norm of the square matrix.

**Question:** Given that the distribution of the entries of $X$ satisfy some assumptions, we have the result that $\|X\|_{\text{op}}<C$ almost surely for some constant $C$ -- this is a known result that we can take for granted. If I were to generate another rectangular matrix $Y$ in the same manner, i.e., each entry of $Y$ is generated independently and identically with the same distribution as the entries of $X$, does the previous result (i.e., $\|X\|_{\text{op}}<C$ almost surely) imply that $\|Y\|_{\text{op}}<C$ almost surely for some constant $C$? Thanks.

**Remark:** I have avoided stating the result in full as it makes the question unnecessarily complex. But for completeness the result that I am looking at is from this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.02945), Theorem 2.7 and Eq. (2.4).

Comment: You can think of $m,n$ matvec $Bx$ as performing $m,m$ matvec $Ax$, then dropping $m-n$ entries. Dropping entries doesn't grow the vector, so $\|Ax\|<c\Rightarrow \|Bx\|<c$

Comment: Sorry but I don't quite follow what "matvec" is?

Comment: matrix vector multiplication